# How can a non-fiat currency be backed by gold?

Tags: money

Question is really simple-

The value of gold is it self controlled by supply-demand, which insinuates that gold is fiat, only valued because people accept it and not because it has a use case. from Wikipedia "Fiat money does not have significant intrinsic value or use value".
so if gold is fiat, how does it back a currency? how is a currency backed by gold, not a fiat?

Comment: Welcome to Economics:SE. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, [we expect questions to provide evidence of prior research](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help), and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: @1muflon1 ok, will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

> The value of gold is it self controlled by supply-demand, which insinuates that gold is fiat, only valued because people accept it and not because it has a use case.

- Anything traded in a market can be said to be valued by supply and demand. This includes commodities like crude oil, which certainly has a use case.
- Although most interest in gold is for “store of value” purposes, it is used in industrial processes as well as jewelry. That’s the “use value” of gold.